# Are the missions in The Settlers II 10th Anniversary the same as the original missions?

Tags: the-settlers

I played the original version of The Settlers II growing up and I never managed to complete all the missions.

I'm wondering are the missions in the 10th Anniversary edition the same as the originals one as I want to clear these missions and not some newly designed ones?

Comment: No, they are not. that i played the original was a long timr ago, so i may be biased, but the newer ones seemed a lot easier to me. I never beat the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the rough storyline is the same, the missions themselves are different. It has been ages that i played the original, so i am not sure really sure how the difficulty differs, but i never beat the original (got stuck in the second to last mission), but i beat the 10th Anniversary.

If you have access to the original game, you can load the old maps as skirmish maps.
To do so, you need locate the old maps. For me, they are located in the folder \DATA\MAPS of the classic game.
Copy them somewhere, and change the file ending from WLD to SWD.
Launch the editor of 10th Anniversary, and change the setting to load classic worlds.
After the world has loaded, save it without changing anything to \data\maps\freeGameMaps of the Anniversary edition.
This will allow you to load the maps, but i have not (yet) played a map this way, so i do not know if the AI works correctly. Also you won't get the story snippets, and the map will not be automatically won when you reach the portal. Neither will you have any limitations of the origiginal campaign, you will have access to all buildings and will start with default ressources.
Also very important: you will have to edit any map that requires you to build a harbor. The lots for harbors are lost this way and you need to manually flatten some land where the harbours should be placeable. When you see an anchor symbol in the editor, that plot is valid for a harbor.

Keep in mind that there are also some minor tweaks in the game mechanics. Newly built military buildings default to not getting any coins. No more wasting coins for not stopping the delivery fast enough! Another change is, that if you reduce the amount of active soldiers to zero, even the last soldier can leave the building now. No more Soldiers stuck in inland barracks anymore!